# segue error in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I have `UITableViewController` and two `UIViewController`. Each controller has a `UINavigationController`. I made two segue the first from `UITableViewCell` and the second from `UIBarButtonItem` with help of Storyboard. When I move from `UITableViewCell` I have a success but when I move from `UIBarButtonItem` I get a error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". 
[image]

Still I made the segue into the code. This code

```
@IBAction func addMusic(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("addMusic", sender: self)
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("listenMusic", sender: nil)
    }
```

This error
[image]

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var nameOfObjectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row] // default it's name and
    var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var wayToFile = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
    var passMusicFileURL: NSURL? // for pass mp3

    if let documentPath: NSURL = wayToFile.first as? NSURL {
        let musicFile = documentPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(nameOfObjectForPass)
        println(musicFile)
        passMusicFileURL = musicFile
    }

    var currentTrackPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

    var allIndexTable = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()! as! [NSIndexPath]

    var currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row

    if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {
        var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController
        playerVC.nameMusicFile = nameOfObjectForPass // name
        playerVC.mp3URL = passMusicFileURL 

        // test 
        playerVC.currentPath = currentTrackPath

        playerVC.allIndex = allIndexTable
        //
        playerVC.currentIndex = currentIndexPath
        // variant the second
        var curRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        playerVC.arrayOfMP3 = listOfMP3Files
        playerVC.currentRow = curRow
    } else if segue.identifier == "add" {
        var avc = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! AddViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code inside of ``override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)``

Comment: In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you are reselecting the row? Why? On the other hand, I'm not sure this is directly related. Did you Ctrl+Drag from button or directly from view controller? If you did from button, then you do not have to create an outlet and perform the segue. It could be that you are performing the segue twice in that case. The other thing I am seeing here also is that you are having two navigation controllers in the same stack. Since Song Table View Controller is already in navigation controller, you do not need to push another navigation controller on the stack.

Comment: @JulianJ.Tejera Yes, I can

Comment: @Legoless I made the segue from UITableViewController but still I made from UITableViewCell and UIBarButtonItem and I got the same error when I passed from UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not preselected any row `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` will return nil and it will crash it this line `var nameOfObjectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row]`.

Try wrapping your operations inside of each conditional statement.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {
        var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var nameOfObjectForPass = listOfMP3Files![indexPath!.row] // default it's name and
        var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        var wayToFile = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
        var passMusicFileURL: NSURL? // for pass mp3

        if let documentPath: NSURL = wayToFile.first as? NSURL {
            let musicFile = documentPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(nameOfObjectForPass)
            println(musicFile)
            passMusicFileURL = musicFile
        }

        var currentTrackPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

        var allIndexTable = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()! as! [NSIndexPath]

        var currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        var playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController
        playerVC.nameMusicFile = nameOfObjectForPass // name
        playerVC.mp3URL = passMusicFileURL

        // test
        playerVC.currentPath = currentTrackPath

        playerVC.allIndex = allIndexTable
        //
        playerVC.currentIndex = currentIndexPath
        // variant the second
        var curRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        playerVC.arrayOfMP3 = listOfMP3Files
        playerVC.currentRow = curRow
    } else if segue.identifier == "add" {
        var avc = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! AddViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Before the if statements you are calling ``tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!``. There might not be any selected row, move it inside the "listenMusic" music block. Basically, move everything above if, inside of the ``listenMusic`` if statement.

Comment: But the segue from UITableViewCell works is good. And the segue from UIBarButtonItem give the error

Comment: The segue for the UITableViewCell will continue to work good, because it has all the necessary prerequisites (i.e.: the selected row). However, when you try to perform the UIBarButtonItem segue it gives you an error because of problem I mentioned. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Change this ..

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("listenMusic", sender: nil)
```

To

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier("listenMusic", sender: self // or if its button then make it button )
```

Comment: I made like you wrote, but it also gave the same error.

Comment: I only cannot to move from a button

Comment: Have you named  all the segue identifier and make sure to use the same name of the segue that you dragged from UIBarButtonItem in the code too..

Comment: what is the identifier name of the segue that goes from your BarButton to other NavigationControllerView

Comment: Yes, I have the same names. I can show you screenshots

Comment: Identifier has name is "add" which from UIBarButtonItem and other identifier has name is "listenMusic" which from UITableViewCell

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
@IBAction func addMusic(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("add", sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: I re-edited the segue identifier here becuz you told the segue identifier name is "add" but change it if you change the segue identifier in future

Comment: Hey you didnt change the sender parameter to sender . Do this sender : sender

Comment: Hey Dont DownVote if it doesnt work , Im losing points here whenevr you downVote my answer